# ¿Cómo crear archivo xml?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

¿Cómo puedo crear un archivo `xml` con este formato mediante código C#?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
   <Areas>
   <area_id>01</area_id>
   <descripcion>HUANCAYO</descripcion>
   </Areas>
</DocumentElement>
```

Con varios elementos me sale esto:

[image: xml]

No puedo leer la parte de la descripción. Me sale toda la descripción concatenada.

Comment: tiene que respetar la forma en como los elementos se agregan unos a otros, estudio un poco los parametros de XElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar [linq to xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/mt693062.aspx)

```
    var doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), 
        new XElement("DocumentElement",
                        new XElement("Areas",
                            new XElement("area_id", "01"), 
                            new XElement("descripcion", "HUANCAYO"))));
```

recuerda definir

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Comment: Hola Leandro eso lo que había hecho pero me sale como muestra la imagen espero se pueda ver, cuando leeo el archivo la parte de la la descripcion me sale todas las descripciones concatenadas.